# seq2seq inference outputs wrong results despite high accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, seq2seq

I am training a seq2seq model following Keras tutorial https://keras.io/examples/nlp/lstm_seq2seq/, the same code but a different dataset.
Here is the main model code for reference:

Code snippet for data preparation:

```
for i, (input_text, target_text) in enumerate(zip(input_texts, target_texts)):
    for t, char in enumerate(input_text):
        encoder_input_data[i, t, input_token_index[char]] = 1.0
    encoder_input_data[i, t + 1 :, input_token_index[" "]] = 1.0
    for t, char in enumerate(target_text):
        # decoder_target_data is ahead of decoder_input_data by one timestep
        decoder_input_data[i, t, target_token_index[char]] = 1.0
        if t > 0:
            # decoder_target_data will be ahead by one timestep
            # and will not include the start character.
            decoder_target_data[i, t - 1, target_token_index[char]] = 1.0
    decoder_input_data[i, t + 1 :, target_token_index[" "]] = 1.0
    decoder_target_data[i, t:, target_token_index[" "]] = 1.0
```

For training:

```
# Define an input sequence and process it.
encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None, num_encoder_tokens))
encoder = keras.layers.LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)

# We discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None, num_decoder_tokens))

# We set up our decoder to return full output sequences,
# and to return internal states as well. We don't use the
# return states in the training model, but we will use them in inference.
decoder_lstm = keras.layers.LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = keras.layers.Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation="softmax")
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

# Define the model that will turn
# `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model = keras.Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
model.summary()
```

Here is the accuracy I got:

```
Epoch 1/5
1920/1920 [==============================] - 818s 426ms/step - loss: 0.2335 - accuracy: 0.9319 - val_loss: 0.2244 - val_accuracy: 0.9350
Epoch 2/5
1920/1920 [==============================] - 947s 493ms/step - loss: 0.2032 - accuracy: 0.9410 - val_loss: 0.1976 - val_accuracy: 0.9430
Epoch 3/5
1920/1920 [==============================] - 879s 458ms/step - loss: 0.1799 - accuracy: 0.9482 - val_loss: 0.1807 - val_accuracy: 0.9483
Epoch 4/5
1920/1920 [==============================] - 832s 433ms/step - loss: 0.1599 - accuracy: 0.9545 - val_loss: 0.1570 - val_accuracy: 0.9562
Epoch 5/5
1920/1920 [==============================] - 774s 403ms/step - loss: 0.1442 - accuracy: 0.9594 - val_loss: 0.1580 - val_accuracy: 0.9548
```

Here is the inference model:

```
encoder_inputs = model.input[0]  # input_1
encoder_outputs, state_h_enc, state_c_enc = model.layers[2].output  # lstm_1
encoder_states = [state_h_enc, state_c_enc]
encoder_model = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)

decoder_inputs = model.input[1]  # input_2
decoder_state_input_h = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_state_input_c = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
decoder_lstm = model.layers[3]
decoder_outputs, state_h_dec, state_c_dec = decoder_lstm(
    decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs
)
decoder_states = [state_h_dec, state_c_dec]
decoder_dense = model.layers[4]
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
decoder_model = keras.Model(
    [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs, [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states
)
def decode_sequence(input_seq):
    # Encode the input as state vectors.
    states_value = encoder_model.predict(input_seq)

    # Generate empty target sequence of length 1.
    target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1, num_decoder_tokens))
    # Populate the first character of target sequence with the start character.
    target_seq[0, 0, target_token_index["\t"]] = 1.0

    # Sampling loop for a batch of sequences
    # (to simplify, here we assume a batch of size 1).
    stop_condition = False
    decoded_sentence = ""
    while not stop_condition:
        output_tokens, h, c = decoder_model.predict([target_seq] + states_value)

        # Sample a token
        sampled_token_index = np.argmax(output_tokens[0, -1, :]) #greedy approach 
        sampled_char = reverse_target_char_index[sampled_token_index]
        decoded_sentence += sampled_char

        # Exit condition: either hit max length
        # or find stop character.
        if sampled_char == "\n" or len(decoded_sentence) > max_decoder_seq_length:
            stop_condition = True

        # Update the target sequence (of length 1).
        target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1, num_decoder_tokens))
        target_seq[0, 0, sampled_token_index] = 1.0

        # Update states
        states_value = [h, c]
    return decoded_sentence
for seq_index in range(5):
    # Take one sequence (part of the training set)
    # for trying out decoding.
    input_seq = X_test[seq_index : seq_index + 1]
    decoded_sentence = decode_sequence(input_seq)
    print("-")
    print("Input sentence:", input_texts[seq_index])
    print("Decoded sentence:", decoded_sentence)
```

However, the output I am getting is almost random. What could be the reason behind that? the accuracy is increasing in the training, and the loss is decreasing as well.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to shift the target sequence when computing the loss.

At the training time, the decoder sequence needs to be shifted such that (n-1)-th predicts the n-th word. For sequence w1 w2 w3 w4 with beginning-of-sentence token [BOS] and end-of-sentence token [EOS] like this:

```
BOS w1  w2  w3  w4
↓   ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓
▯ → ▯ → ▯ → ▯ → ▯  
↓   ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓
w1  w2  w3  w4  EOS
```

Generally speaking: you feed the decoder with the target sequence without the last token and compute the loss with respect to the target sequence without the first token.

When you don't do this, the decoder looks like this:

```
w1  w2  w3  w4
↓   ↓   ↓   ↓
▯ → ▯ → ▯ → ▯
↓   ↓   ↓   ↓
w1  w2  w3  w4
```

The model quickly learns to copy the input tokens, and the loss rapidly decreases, but the model does not learn to translate.

The inputs to the decoder should be `decoder_inputs[:, :-1]`, the targets should be `decoder_inputs[:, 1:]` after you add special symbols at the beginning and the end of the decoder sequence.

Comment: But that has been implemented (I added the code that shows that at the beginning). Based on what I found, this seems as a consequence of the teacher-forcing training approach. Not sure how to overcome that.